# Describe process.env in jsdoc

Tags: jsdoc

I use [Dotenv-Webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack). So, in js code I can do something like:

```js
console.log(process.env.DB_HOST);
```

But I want to have autocomplete for values from my .env file.

[image]

Comment: Is this related to any specific IDE?

Comment: @NicoHaase I use VS Code, but jsdoc isn't related to any IDE
(honestly, I also use ts (`@typedef {{id: string, role: string }} User`) in jsdoc, and I'm not sure if this is allowed in jsDoc without IDE)

Comment: JSDoc might not be related to the IDE, but to parse all available variables from `.env` you might need a plugin for your IDE, and this is usually not a general plugin for multiple IDEs, but one developed specially for **one** IDE

Comment: @NicoHaase I use Dotenv-Webpack to parse .env. And I want to describe it by myself. For example I can do it so:

```js
/** @typedef {{API_URL:   string; FB_KEY: string }} Env

/** @type {Env} */
const env = process.env;
*/
```

But I don't want to describe `const env`, I want to describe `process.env`